# Is there a way to alternate the order of a result based off one id while keeping groupings based off another id in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, union, window-functions

I have this query in Postgresql:

```
(SELECT q.question, q.category_id, a.id, a.question_id, a.answer
    FROM questions q, answers a
    WHERE q.id = a.question_id
    AND category_id = 1
    AND question_id
    BETWEEN (SELECT property FROM users WHERE email = 'test@test.com')
    AND (SELECT property FROM users WHERE email = 'test@test.com') + 14)
    
    UNION
    
(SELECT q.question, q.category_id, a.id, a.question_id, a.answer
    FROM questions q, answers a
    WHERE q.id = a.question_id
    AND category_id = 2
    AND question_id
    BETWEEN (SELECT laws FROM users WHERE email = 'test@test.com')
    AND (SELECT laws FROM users WHERE email = 'test@test.com') + 16)
    
ORDER BY question_id, id
```

that currently returns results in this format:

```
+-----------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
|          question           | category_id | question_id | answer |
+-----------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| What color is the sky?      |           1 |          16 | blue   |
| What color is the sky?      |           1 |          16 | green  |
| What color is the sky?      |           1 |          16 | purple |
| What color is the sky?      |           1 |          16 | red    |
| What color is a firetruck?  |           1 |          17 | orange |
| What color is a firetruck?  |           1 |          17 | teal   |
| What color is a firetruck?  |           1 |          17 | red    |
| What color is a firetruck?  |           1 |          17 | green  |
| What color is dirt?         |           2 |          18 | green  |
| What color is dirt?         |           2 |          18 | green  |
| What color is dirt?         |           2 |          18 | green  |
| What color is dirt?         |           2 |          18 | green  |
+-----------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

What I want to do is alternate the order based off the category_id, so the category id would be alternating like this: 1,2,1,2, but I want to keep the groups based off the question_id. So the result would look like this:

```
+-----------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
|          question           | category_id | question_id | answer |
+-----------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| What color is the sky?      |           1 |          16 | blue   |
| What color is the sky?      |           1 |          16 | green  |
| What color is the sky?      |           1 |          16 | purple |
| What color is the sky?      |           1 |          16 | red    |
| What color is dirt?         |           2 |          18 | green  |
| What color is dirt?         |           2 |          18 | green  |
| What color is dirt?         |           2 |          18 | green  |
| What color is dirt?         |           2 |          18 | green  |
| What color is a firetruck?  |           1 |          17 | orange |
| What color is a firetruck?  |           1 |          17 | teal   |
| What color is a firetruck?  |           1 |          17 | red    |
| What color is a firetruck?  |           1 |          17 | green  |
+-----------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

I've tried to using `ORDER BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t.category_id ORDER BY t.category_id)`
but that just results in each being alternated without being grouped by question_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the following `order by` clause:

```
order by 
    rank() over(partition by category_id order by question_id),
    question_id,
    id
```

Basically this interleaves the categories/questions tuples.

Notes:

- use standard, explicit joins (`from ... join ... on`) rather than old-school, implicit joins (`from ..., ... where ...`); this is prehistoric syntax, that should not be used in new code
- it is rather likely that your query could be simplified to not use `union`; if you were to ask another question with sample data, and desired results, one might be able to suggest